# Colliding 2 times with the same object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, collider

I want to start by saying that I need some guidance, the first thing is that **my player is colliding with the upgrade(Cube) object 2 times** every time, so instead of receiving 2damage, I receive 4 damage.
This is the colliding code:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Upgrade") && this != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Collide:" + other.name);

            Upgrades upgradesScript = other.GetComponent<Upgrades>();
            
            if(upgradesScript != null)
            {
                Damage += upgradesScript.Damage;
                Health += upgradesScript.Health;
                Xspeed += upgradesScript.Xspeed;

            }

        }

    }
```

And here is the upgrade script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Upgrades : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float Damage; //id 0
    public float Xspeed; //id 1
    public float Health; //id 2
    public float itemID;
    public float stage = 1;



    void Start()
    {
        if(itemID == 0)
        {
            RandomDamage();
        }
        else if(itemID == 1)
        {
            RandomXspeed();
        }
        else
        {
            RandomHealth();
        }

  
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void RandomDamage()
    {
        Damage = Random.Range(1 , 3 );
    }

    public void RandomXspeed()
    {
       Xspeed = Random.Range(1 * stage, 3 * stage);

    }

    public void RandomHealth()
    {
        Health = Random.Range(5 , 10 );

    }

}
```

This is from inspector:

[image]

**Now, if you could also tell me** if I took the right approach, or what could I do to optimize my code more, regarding the switch instead of if's, I heard is better but I don't fully understand how it is better that's why I haven't used it.
Thank you!

Comment: well once you hit, you have added the event, then if you hit again you add it agian so then you will do the same code twice, on the 3rd hit you will run the same code 4 times...

Comment: @BugFinder I am not sure I understand, sorry if I did not explained myself good enough
But I have a cube that I walk in and is suppose to give me let's say damage, but only once and instead that same cube is performing 2 times.
I've implemented this code witch seems to work:

private bool hasEntered = false;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (!hasEntered)
    {
       my code...
hasEntered = true;
    }
}

Comment: @BugFinder I don't think there are events here .. the `+=` are modifying some properties/fields

Comment: Why is your `itemID` a `float` ..? Should probably rather be an `public enum ItemType{ Damage, Health, XSpeed }` and then `public ItemType itemID;` instead

Comment: @derHugo dang, i clearly misread .. somehow i read the randoms as the ones in use :p would have explained the multiple calls though..

Comment: Does your player have more than 1 collider? The code looks right to me

Comment: @Cyclone6664 I created an empty gameObject called Player and i gave him a box collider but he has a child( 3Dobject with capsule collider).
However, the script I have is attached just to the Player gameObject that have only 1 Box Collider.
Thank you all for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Regarding switch vs if statements, switches have at least two main advantages.

1. They are faster, even if only slightly for smaller numbers of cases. This is because with switches, the compiler generates a "jump table". This means that it checks "what case to go to", while if statements check "if each case can be satisfied".
2. It's more readable, which is very important. Each case is a lot shorter than any if statement, and the more unique word choice and structure means it will blend in less with the rest of your code.

If statements can have a lot more variety and are good if you have multiple elements to track, or one condition much more likely than the others, but if you're only making multiple options based on the condition of one element, always use a switch.

Additionally, they're very good for enums, which I think you should use here. If you don't know, an enum is a set of named values called elements. In effect, they CAN work just like ints, but are much more readable and easy to remember (especially in editor).

So, for your if statements, try this instead.

```cs
    public float Damage; //id 0
    public float Xspeed; //id 1
    public float Health; //id 2
    public UpgradeTypes itemID; //Will default to damage
    public float stage = 1;
    
    public enum UpgradeTypes
    {
        Damage,
        Speed,
        Health
    }
    
    void Start () {
        switch (itemID)
        {
            case UpgradeTypes.Damage:
                RandomDamage();
                break;
            case UpgradeTypes.Speed:
                RandomXspeed();
                break;
            case UpgradeTypes.Health:
                RandomHealth();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here are a few articles and videos for more details on switches.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f9PMeYbnMc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjUG_y5ZaL4
[https://medium.com/@michellekwong2/switch-vs-if-else-1d458e7b0711#:~:text=A%20switch%20statement%20works%20much,case%20has%20to%20be%20executed](https://medium.com/@michellekwong2/switch-vs-if-else-1d458e7b0711#:%7E:text=A%20switch%20statement%20works%20much,case%20has%20to%20be%20executed).

As for your main question. My first recommendation is to add an `OnTriggerEnter` method to your Upgrades script, and have this `Debug.Log` the name of whatever collider object it comes into contact with. This will let you know if it's the same player collider hitting the upgrades twice, or two different ones.

Because if your player has a rigidbody (and I can only assume it does), then any and all colliders it has, even if they're attached to child objects, will trigger the `OnTriggerEnter()`.
E.G. if you have a main collider and a smaller collider on a child for checking walls or something, both will trigger the Upgrades object.

If the issue is the effects being called twice, a simple bool can make it only be done so once.

```cs
    private bool didUpgradeThisFrame;
            
    public void LateUpdate() 
    {
            didUpgradeThisFrame = false;
    }
            
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
                    if (other.CompareTag("Upgrade") && this != null)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Collide:" + other.name);
            
                        Upgrades upgradesScript = other.GetComponent<Upgrades>();
                        
                        if(upgradesScript != null && !didUpgradeThisFrame)
                        {
                            didUpgradeThisFrame = true;
                            Damage += upgradesScript.Damage;
                            Health += upgradesScript.Health;
                            Xspeed += upgradesScript.Xspeed;
            
                        }
            
                    }
    }
```